# SQL Get first match of a ranked sort performance tuning

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, performance-testing, query-performance

I have a query that will take a distinct list of values and get the first match based off a ranked sort that works well for small scale work. The problem is that when I apply this to large scale work (35,000 unique entries against 40000 records) the query just clocks and hangs.

As an experiment I did just the first half of the query and it took about 3 - 4 minutes on the 40k rows (see below for what I mean). I already changed the left joins to inner joins with a slight performance enhancement, but I am running out of ideas on what else I can do.

**Note**
If at all possible I want to stay with non-proprietary standards based SQL as much as possible since I will likely be changing from MS SQL Server to MySQL or Oracle in the near future and I don't want to do needless rewrites.

**Query**

```
SELECT Q.*
FROM (
SELECT 
    A.name
  , B.id
  , B.status
  , B.rank

FROM TestA A
LEFT JOIN TestB B
ON B.name = A.name
WHERE 
  B.rank = (
            SELECT MIN(B2.rank) 
            FROM TestB B2 
            WHERE B.name = B2.name
           )
) Q
-- by first half I mean what is above this line here
WHERE
    Q.id = (
        SELECT MIN(Q2.id) 
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                A.name
              , B.id
              , B.status
              , B.rank

            FROM TestA A
            LEFT JOIN TestB B
            ON B.name = A.name
            WHERE 
              B.rank = (
                        SELECT MIN(B2.rank) 
                        FROM TestB B2 
                        WHERE B.name = B2.name
                       )
        ) Q2 
        WHERE Q.name = Q2.name
       )
;
```

**Schema:** of test data

```
CREATE TABLE TestA
(`name` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO TestA
(`name`)
VALUES
('bob'),
('john'),
('will')
;

CREATE TABLE TestB
(`name` varchar(4), `id` int, `status` varchar(18), `rank` int)
;

INSERT INTO TestB
(`name`, `id`, `status`, `rank`)
VALUES
('bob', 11, 'happy', 1),
('bob', 12, 'active', 1),
('bob', 93, 'inactive', 2),
('bob', 94, 'canceled', 2),
('bob', 95, 'pending deletion', 3),
('john', 32, 'pending activation', 10),
('john', 24, 'inactive', 4),
('will', 555, 'vacation', 5),
('will', 511, 'vacation', 5),
('will', 661, 'on hold', 9)
;
```

Here is a fiddle I made of the schema and code

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e91a8/3/0

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The fiddle is mysql, but you have tagged the question with sql-server.

Comment: I reread the post and see that you mentions the DBMS there. The problem is that both sql-server and Oracle accepts a whole lot more sql-standard than mysql. For your problem, CTE's and OLAP functions will be useful, oracle and msql supports these, mysql does not.

Comment: I am more concerned with the actual performance.. it takes about 20 minutes for it to run on 40k rows of data .. that data will probably grow by 5k to 10k a year which makes it ugly long term.. and the changes to the environment are just going to be a big annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd like to mention is you are joining on name and I am assuming you haven't added any index into this column (schema does not have any index defined). If you can rather use an auto increment ID in TableA and use that as a foreign key in TableB, using join with ID would greatly speed up your query.

I'd also recommend that you run the profiler in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) while running the query if you have admin privileges. You can also check out sqlsentry which claims to be better than SSMS for profiling. http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view (I haven't tried it but looks promising).

Let me know if the indexes help or not.

Comment: Indexes are already present and tuned in the production database although not in the example out of brevity. I am using profiler tool but will definitely check out sentry to see if it is be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Joining on a string, as mentioned is bad... that said, this query should be slightly faster, and compatible with SQL Server & MySQL (unsure on Oracle).

```
SELECT A.name, B.id, B.status, B.rank
FROM TestA A
INNER JOIN TestB B 
   ON A.name = B.name
   INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM TestB GROUP BY name) AS MinID
      ON B.id = MinID.id
```

[The Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e91a8/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    A.name
  , B.id
  , B.status
  , B.rank
FROM TestA A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.id ORDER BY B.rank) rownum
        FROM B
    ) b1
    WHERE rownum = 1
) B
ON B.name = A.name
```

Comment: You probably meant to partition on Name right? And ordering by Rank is ambiguous since rank is not unique within a partition. Looks like OP wants the lowest ID for duplicates of Rank so just ad ID as the second order by column and this will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.....

```
SELECT A.Name
      ,B.ID
      ,B.[Status]
      ,B.[Rank]
FROM TestA A 
INNER JOIN 
          (
           SELECT name, id, status, rank
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY [Rank] ASC) rn
           FROM TestB
          ) B
ON A.Name = B.Name 
WHERE B.RN = 1
```

### [WORKING SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11166/3)

Comment: Ordering by Rank is ambiguous since rank is not unique within a partition. Looks like OP wants the lowest ID for duplicates of Rank so just ad ID as the second order by column and this will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that works both in SQL Server and MySQL. Probably a bit slower than using `row_number()`.

```
select A.Name,
       B1.id,
       B1.status,
       B1.rank
from TestB as B1
  inner join (
             select B3.name,
                    B3.rank,
                    min(B3.id) as id 
             from (
                    select B4.name,
                           B4.id,
                           B4.rank
                    from TestB as B4
                      inner join (
                                 select min(B6.rank) as rank,
                                        B6.name
                                 from TestB as B6
                                 group by B6.name
                                 ) as B5
                        on B4.name = B5.name and
                           B4.rank = B5.rank
                  ) as B3
             group by B3.Name, 
                      B3.rank
             ) as B2
    on B1.name = B2.Name and
       B1.rank = B2.rank and
       B1.id = B2.id
  inner join TestA as A
    on B1.name = A.name
```